# Как реализовать обрезку и ресайз изображения  ?

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, javascript

Как сделать обрезку и резайна изображения на сайте (подобна реализация есть вконтакте)
как такое реализовать ?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Их [полно](https://www.google.ru/search?q=javascript+Image+Cropping&oq=javascript+Image+Cropping), например

[Jcrop » the jQuery Image Cropping Plugin](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html)

> Jcrop is the quick and easy way to add image cropping functionality to your web application. It combines the ease-of-use of a typical jQuery plugin with a powerful cross-platform DHTML cropping engine that is faithful to familiar desktop graphics applications.